# How can I convert my normal timestamp into a BSON timestamp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, timestamp, bson

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

mongodb has turned my timestamp into BSON (I know this is normal)

my timestamp is this `641912491` where as in the database it looks like this `1457904327000.000000`.

I have a document with a key named `date_in_the_past` which holds my timestamp in it's BSON form.

> Note: I am fully aware that the mongodb _id key holds a date but it is of no use to me in this scenario as, that would be the date when the document was written to the db (not the date in the past that I am looking for)

**How can I convert my normal timestamp into a BSON timestamp?**

I have tried to understand [mongodb/js-bson](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson) and [mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/timestamp.js](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/timestamp.js) but I can't see how to do it.

example of what I am looking to do:

```
var past=timestampToBSON(641912491);
db.collection('docs').find({date_in_the_past:past}).limit(1).toArray(function(e,r){});
```

Comment: Did you try just using a javascript date object `var past = new Date(641912491 * 1000)`

Comment: yes that just gives me `Sat May 05 1990 14:01:31 GMT+0100 (BST)`

Comment: Isn't that the date you're trying to look up ?

Comment: I need to look it up with BSON don't I? `db.collection('docs').find({date_in_the_past:1457904327000.000000})`

Comment: Not really, if you stored a date object, you'd look up a date object, MongoDB only stores it internally as BSON, you don't have to pass it BSON

Comment: Robomongo client ui tells me that it's data type is `Double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's stored as a bson timestamp object, you could do something like this

```
var Timestamp = require('mongodb').Timestamp; 

var past = Timestamp(641912491,1);
db.collection('docs').find({date_in_the_past:past})
```

or

```
db.collection('docs').find({date_in_the_past: Timestamp(641912491,1)})
```

it has some more info and examples about it here
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps

Comment: What does the second parameter mean? Is it always `1`?

Comment: You can use `Timestamp.fromNumber(641912491)`. on `Timestamp(x, y)` the second parameter is used for higher precision numbers